# Rails 3 Time Comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have my movies page and I'm trying to make the movie status automatically change depending on the release_date

I have this so far, but it doesnt seem to work

```
<% if  @movie.release_date.strftime("%d %B %Y") >  Time.now.strftime("%d %B %Y") %>
    Released
  <% else if  @movie.release_date.strftime("%d %B %Y") <  Time.now.strftime("%d %B %Y") %>
    Upcoming
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can i make it so that if the release date I put in the form (day month year) is before the current date (day month year), it puts "Released" and then vice versa for "Upcoming" so if the release date is after the current date (day month year)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% if @movie.release_date.past? %>
  Released
<% else %>
  Upcoming
<% end %>
```

Don't use string for comparison, compare the original object.